# grails g:select item as optionValue

Tags: javascript, grails, select

i have domain class:

> ```
> class Template {
>   String name;
>   String prop1;
>   String prop2;
> }
> ```

and view with g:select:

> ```
> <g:select name="template.id" from="${Template.list()}" optionKey="id" onclick = "updateEditText(this.value);"/>
> ```

i need to set selected object to g:select value (but not String), i think it should be something like this (but it's not working):

> ```
> <g:select name="template.id" from="${Template.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue = "${it}" onclick = "updateEditText(this.value);"/>
> ```

*it - object from template.list()

my procedure updateEditText need to take all properties from selected object:

> ```
> <g: javascript>
>    updateEditText(obj) {
>       document.getElementByID("prop1").value = obj.prop1;
>       document.getElementByID("prop2").value = obj.prop2; //etc
>    }
> </g:javascript>
> ```

if I use "prop1" or "prop2" for optionvalue it works fine, but it's not what I need.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object from html input to javascript. But you can use remoteFunction tag to pass the selected id to server, where the object is retrieved and properties returned. Like this:

```
<g:select name="template.id" from="${Template.list()}" optionKey="id" 
          onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'getProps', 
          params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
          update: 'props')}"/>
<div id="props">Properties here</div>
```

In the controller you get the instance and render the properties like this:

```
def getProps() {
    def obj = Template.get(params.id)
    render("""<div id="prop1">prop1 = ${obj.prop1}</div>
              <div id="prop2">prop2 = ${obj.prop2}</div>
           """)
}
```

Comment: update: 'props' mean that element with id  = "props" will be updated? Can i update more1 than 1 element with different ids by call remoteFuncion once?   Sorry me for my English is smth wrong.

Comment: You may use "update: [success: 'great', failure: 'ohno']" to switch between 2 elements, based on the status of response, but update to more than one elements at the same time could be confusing. Why do you have to do that?

Comment: I have another class named Cars. When I create object "Car" need to set 4 textField vaules automatically using field values from selected object (template for car model) (it will be count steering axes (1 or 2), count wheel on each(2 or 4) on it, count of leading axes(1..5), count wheel on each (2 or 4)). Then if user have not-standart car (every variants can not be described in car templates), he can change one ore more of this values and save object Car.

Comment: OK, you can let user select a template, use remoteFunction to send the template id to server, which render the 4 textFields with the default values of the model in a form. Then, the user can modify the textFields default value in the form and submit to another method, where the car instance is saved. Is that clear? The point is, you don't have to put all models in one page.

Comment: Yes it is. I would like to do all opereations for create car (save car inctance) in one page. I don't want to let user select car template, then commit template id, then fill all another field for car (such as sign, VIN etc.) and then commit again to save car instance.

Comment: With onchange and Ajax call bundled, users only need to manually commit once. But from coding perspective, you can not put all these steps into one.